# Can I replace a pdf file while Adobe Reader shows this file?

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-reader

I'm often writing documents with LaTeX and for my company I use Windows. Under Linux (e.g. `Ubuntu` and `evince`) it's possible to have a pdf file open while recompiling the document and seeing the changes immediately.

Under `Windows` and `Adobe Reader` I have to close the document and reopen it after recompiling it. Is there a way to recompile the pdf file and see the changes in the opened Adobe Reader?

Comment: A (IMO very practical) workaround would be to switch the PDF reader e.g. to [Sumatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumatra_PDF)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to run other software than the company gives me. So I only can use Adober Reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Adobe PDF reader locks the file.

Comment: And there is no way to change this behavior?

Comment: You could ask Adobe to write a new version of Adobe reader that doesn't use mandatory file locking on open files. Alternatively ask Microsoft to intruduce a mechanism for making mandatory locks be merely advisory (breaking lots of apps). I'm assuming Adobe Reader uses [byte-range locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows), if not you can perhaps amend the PDF-writing software (LaTex etc) to specify the appropriate flags (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546504/how-do-i-make-windows-file-locking-more-like-unix-file-locking). Wait for other answers.